# How to extract a repeated pattern from a word without space

Tags: python, regex, split, python-re

I have the following word: "PANGOLINUPANGO" and would like to split it into ["PANGO","LINUP","PANGO"]. So in general splitting by repeated pattern appearing in the word (not a string with spaces).
I have tried the following Python re expression but can't get what I need:

```
[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(\D)\1*", s)]
```

It can also be like the following: 'VRJAMVRJAM' which should result into ['VRJAM','VRJAM'], so not necessarily non-contiguous repeats.

Comment: Can you give some more examples and expected results? Can there be more repeated parts than 1 part? What if the string is `PANGOLINUPANGOA` ? This will give you 3 capture groups `\b(\w+)(\w*)(\1)\b` https://regex101.com/r/Vb7HfR/1 Why should there be `LINUP` as the second match and not `LINU`

Comment: This is a way too difficult task to be solved with a regex. How difficult it is, exactly, depends on the details. If it is always a word at the very beginning an the end of a string, then it is quite simple, but if you need to find any repeated pattern in general, on an arbitrarily long string, that is a completely different kind of problem.

Comment: Plain regex solution is not possible, here is [a possible solution](https://ideone.com/gvdlvN).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution:

```
(\w+)(\w*)(\1)
```

Creates a group for the first letters, matches any possible (optional) letters in the middle, then matches the same group from the start.